# Rails serving a static page on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails 4.0 I use a redirect to serve a static landing page in my rails application:
`get '/landing', :to => redirect('/landing.html')`

This works locally, but on Heroku, it yields a redirect loop. E.g. in Chrome: `This webpage has a redirect loop`. What would be a good way to avoid this problem on Heroku or otherwise accomplish this static serving in a proper way?